# pass parameter to view function from jinja templates in flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a file.html which contains the following code

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
    {%block content%}
    <p>Done predicting</p>
    <div>
        <p>Choose files to view results</p>
        <label for="txt_file">txt file</label>
        <input type="file" id="txt_file">
        <label for="ann_file">ann file</label>
        <input type="file" id="ann_file">
        <button type="button" onclick="processFile()">Display</button>
        <script>
            function processFile() {
                var t = document.getElementById("txt_file").value;
                var a = document.getElementById("ann_file").value;
                window.location.href='{{url_for('display',txt=t,ann=a)}}';
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    {%endblock%}
```

In my routes.py I have the function

```
@app.route("/display/<txt>/<ann>")
def display(txt,ann):
    return txt + " " + ann
```

When I pass `{{url_for('display',txt='somefile.txt',ann='somefile.ann')}}`
manually I get the url **/display/somefile.txt/somefile.ann**, otherwise it gives **/display//**. Can anyone help? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe you are making a typo error with respect to quotes. Do as:-
`window.location.href='{{url_for(display,txt='+t+',ann='+a+')}}'`

Comment: Doing `window.location.href='{{url_for(display,txt='+t+',ann='+a+')}}` gives the url as **/display/+t+/+a+** which is obvious because you are passing string directly to the url

Comment: Put double quotes as & try:-
`window.location.href="{{url_for(display,txt=t,ann=a)}}"`. These problems appear frequently and u need to do hit and trial to get things working.